# What does בהם refer to in some texts of אַתָּה חונַנְתָּנוּ?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, maariv, nuschaot, motzei-shabbos

In Maariv after Shabbos we insert אַתָּה חונַנְתָּנוּ into the Amidah. In some siddurim the word בהם is introduced making it read 
אַתָּה חונַנְתָּנוּ לְמַדַּע תּורָתֶךָ. וַתְּלַמְּדֵנוּ לַעֲשות **בהם** חֻקֵּי רְצונֶךָ
What is בהם referring to? It seems like in some version there must have been the word like שבתות which has got left out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bach ([Orach Chaim 294](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&st=&pgnum=484)) says that it refers back to מדע תורתך: through our knowledge of Hashem's Torah (besides general knowledge, אתה חונן לאדם דעת, which is equally true of Jews and non-Jews), we are enabled to perform the mitzvos of Hashem's will.

On the other hand, Seder Avodas Yisrael (R. Seligman Baer) [states](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42807&pgnum=319) that it is simply a copyist's or printer's error. (In some versions of ותודיענו - the replacement for אתה חוננתנו used when Yom Tov falls on Motzaei Shabbos - the same phrase is used, and there בהם fits better with its antecedent, את משפטי צדקך. So it is possible that the copyists incorrectly applied it in both places.)

Comment: Isn't mada toratecha singular? It should then be 'bo'.

Comment: @DoubleAA, he might mean that it refers back, actually, to both kinds of knowledge (דעת\בינה in general, as well as מדע תורתך).

Answer (score 1):

R' Hirsch says it refers back to da'as and bina of the first line of the beracha - ata chonen l'adam da'as etc.